# Roll over the month of dates using LocalDate in Java?

Tags: java, date, calendar

I am designing a booking system in java that only has to handle dates for the year 2015 and using the LocalDate class, a booking consists of a start date and a duration e.g.    2015, 5, 26: 7 would be a booking starting on 26 may 2015 for a duration of 7 days,  {26,27,28,29,30,31} May and the {1}st Jun. If i am say generating my dates with a loop is there anyway to get the correct roll over of the month?, so the date won't say be 32nd of May but instead 1st Jun.

```
        int initialDate=26;
        int initialMonth=5; 
        int duration= 7; 
        int endDate= initialDate+duration; 
        LocalDate date; 

        while(initialDate<=endDate){
            date=LocalDate.of(2015, initialMonth, initialDate); 
            System.out.println(date.getDayOfMonth());
            initialDate++; 
        }
```

Comment: Why not use [`LocalDate#plusDays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using Java 8, why not use [`LocalDate#plusDays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)?

```
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2015, 5, 26);
LocalDate endDate = startDate.plusDays(7);

System.out.println(endDate);
```

Which outputs `2015-06-02`

Comment: I am sure you can mention **since JDK 8**?

Comment: @KickButtowski Nah, I just make the OP guess ;) - Besides, even if the OP is using JodaTime, the functionality is almost the same (but JodaTime doesn't have `LocalDate.of` ;))

Comment: FYI, [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.7 code would be quite similar:  `LocalDate ld = new LocalDate( 2015, 5, 26 ).plusDays( 7 );` or …`plusWeeks( 1 )`.