# How can i Increment a date(dd-MM-yyyy) by 90 days in java

Tags: java

i have a situation where the user has to select a date while creating a request and that request will be valid upto 90 days from the date he selected.How would i implement this logic in my code? I tried but i guess i had no logic.

Comment: You might also consider using [JodaTime, for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842934/how-to-add-days-to-java-simple-date-format/21842959#21842959) or [Java 8's Date/Time API, for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29529488/roll-over-the-month-of-dates-using-localdate-in-java/29529532#29529532)

Answer (score 2):

To prase date in format specified "yyyy-MM-dd" you need SimpleDateFormat object and once you have calender object , you can add 90 days to calendar using add() method of calendar. Also you need not need SimpleDateFormat to increment calendar details:

```
       SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy" ); //Not Required
        Date selectedDate=null;
        try {
            selectedDate=dateFormat.parse("10-11-1986");// replace it with selected date
            } catch (ParseException e) {
        }           

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(selectedDate);
        System.out.println(" Selected Date: "+cal.getTime());
        cal.add( Calendar.DATE,90 );
        System.out.println("Date after 90 days: "+cal.getTime());
```

Comment: date format ("dd-MM-yyyy") will come in picture if you are parsing date using parse method. If you are using current date then date format is not required. Alternatively SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd-MM-yyyy" ); will work

Comment: issue is i am using datepicker ie <input style="width:220px !important;" type="text" class="datepicker" data-bvalidator="required" name="quotationDate">......................and in the backend i bind it with  @Column(name = "qdate")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
Date quotationDate;          ...........................it is the requirement ,i need to save the date in this format only

Comment: @MirMajidHussain Kindly check modified code, hope this will help you

Answer (score -1):

You can use the methods setMonth() and getMonth() of Date api.

```
Date date = new Date();
date.setMonth(date.getMonth()+3);
```

Comment: As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, int month).

Comment: Three months is not exactly the same as 90 days.